# Avoiding long integers (32 bit) in Simulink-generated code

Tags: simulink

I'm working with some signal processing code (C language) generated by Matlab Simulink, targetting a DSP with 24-bit integers. The code that Simulink generated relies upon the existence of 32-bit integers and uses them in calculations, only at the end truncating the higher-order bits into the 24-bit result. Unfortunately the compiler for this architecture targets a limited subset of C and doesn't currently support 32-bit longs, instead having short/int/long all as the same 24-bit integer.

We've tried specifying the bit-widths of the integer types for the custom processor target as 24 bits, however this gave errors and the [documentation for hardware targets](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/hardware-targets.html#bqzb34e) appears to confirm that this is not permitted (3rd bullet):

> The Number of bits parameters describe the native word size of the microprocessor and the bit lengths of char, short, int, and long data. For code generation to succeed:
>
> - The bit lengths must be such that char <= short <= int <= long.
> - Bit lengths must be multiples of 8, with a maximum of 32.
> - The bit length for long data must not be less than 32.

However as a Simulink neophyte it's quite possible I'm looking in the wrong places - is it in fact possible to have Simulink target a device with only 24-bit integers?